# EF4 CTP5 Database First + Many-To-Many Relation (Error)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm pretty sure it's something regarding hidden conventions, but I always get an error when trying to map a many-to-many relation to an existing database.
Here is the simplest example:

```
[Table("ALRole", SchemaName = "AL")]
public class Role
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

[Table("ALUser", SchemaName = "AL")]
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I got the usual three tables in the db: the first two are obvious, and the third is created with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE AL.ALUsersRoles
(
    RoleID int NOT NULL,
    UserID int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ALUserRole PRIMARY KEY(RoleID, UserID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ALUserRole_RoleID FOREIGN KEY(RoleID) REFERENCES AL.ALRole(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ALUserRole_UserID FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES AL.ALUser(ID)
)
```

Now I try to map the many-to-many relation, with code like this:

```
// ...I'm in the EntityTypeConfiguration-derived class (User)
HasMany(u => u.Roles)
    .WithMany(r => r.Users)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey(u => u.ID, "UserID");
        m.MapRightKey(r => r.ID, "RoleID");
        ToTable("ALUsersRoles", "AL");
    });
```

I tried all the possibile combinations and variations in this code, but I always get the error:

```
{"Invalid column name 'Name'.\r\nInvalid ...and so on...
```

So I think it must be the table that is not created correctly.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance
Andrea
P.S.: I stripped down some of my code, so maybe there can be some small typo...

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: This is code first, not Database first.

Answer (score 1):

well, this works for me same as OP.

```
        //many-to-many between *Users -> Web_User_Rol <- Web_Rol*
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Web_Rols).WithMany(r => r.Users)
            .Map(t=>t.MapLeftKey("user_id")
                     .MapRightKey("roleID")
                     .ToTable("Web_User_Rol"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your object model or fluent API code. I've used them and they perfectly created the desired schema without any exception. I think your problem comes from another entity (perhaps one with a *"Name"* property) unrelated to what you've shown here. To find that, drop (or rename) your existing database and let Code First create one for you and then compare the 2 databases and see what is different.